# Upgrading a theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an already functional wordpress site. But I would like to make some changes to the grid.css and HTML file that I created for the theme I am using on the site. I tried editing the file in the dashboard but couldn't find the grid.css. What's the easiest way to do this. Do I have to copy all my files up grade them then install the new theme in wordpress?

Comment: Are you comfortable using Cyberduck to login via FTP? Your hosting co will help you to do this to get to the actual files. Edit with any text editor (SublimeText 2)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that grid.css related to the some plugin? Then go to the dashboard - plugins - editor. On the right side u can coose plugin and check files.

Answer (score 0):

You can always edit files directly in your theme folder, just like the dashboard does. If you have FTP/SCP/SFTP access to your site, give notepad++ with [nppFTP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/) or a similar tool a try.

If you have no direct access to your wordpress installation, you can use [WPEditor](http://wpeditor.net/) which runs as a wordpress plugin by itself. It does some comfortable code highlighting, too.